# Proof of the reflective property of the ellipese

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I'm trying to prove the reflection property of the ellipses for an optics problem. The property is that that a ray of light originated at one of the ellipse's foci reflects in such a way to pass through the other focus.

The simplest way I figured out to prove this is to prove that a line connecting one of the focus to any point of the ellipse has the same angle with the normal at that point as a line connecting the other focus with the same point.

So... Let

$\frac{\displaystyle x^2}{\displaystyle a^2}+\frac{\displaystyle y^2}{\displaystyle b^2}=1\,\,\,\rightarrow\,\,\,y=\pm b\sqrt{1-\frac{\displaystyle x^2}{\displaystyle b^2}}$

be the ellipse equation. The foci are at positions $(0,\pm f)$ where $f=\sqrt{b^2-a^2}$.

The lines connecting the foci to the point $(x_{0},y_{0})$ have equations:

$line\,1\,\,\,y=y_{0}+\left(\frac{\displaystyle y_{0}-f}{\displaystyle x_{0}}\right)(x-x_{0})$

$line\,2\,\,\,y=y_{0}+\left(\frac{\displaystyle y_{0}+f}{\displaystyle x_{0}}\right)(x-x_{0})$

and the line equation of the normal to the point $(x_{0},y_{0})$ is

$y=y_{0}-\frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle y'(x_{0})}(x-x_{0})$
$=y_{0}+\frac{\displaystyle a^2}{\displaystyle b^2}\frac{\displaystyle y(x_{0})}{\displaystyle x_{0}}(x-x_{0}).$

The angle between line 1 and the normal is then

$\theta_{1}=\arctan\left(\frac{\displaystyle a^2}{\displaystyle b^2}\frac{\displaystyle y_{0}}{\displaystyle x_{0}}\right)-\arctan\left(\frac{\displaystyle y_{0}-f}{\displaystyle x_{0}}\right)$

And the angle between line 2 and the normal is

$\theta_{2}=\arctan\left(\frac{\displaystyle y_{0}+f}{\displaystyle x_{0}}\right)-\arctan\left(\frac{\displaystyle a^2}{\displaystyle b^2}\frac{\displaystyle y_{0}}{\displaystyle x_{0}}\right)$

And so... I'm trying to proof (with no success still) that $\theta_{1}=\theta{2}$.

Could you lend me a tip?

Thank you very much.

Comment: hint tan (-x) = -tan (x) because of parity

Comment: That allows me to show that $\theta_{1}(y_{0})=\theta_{2}(-y_{0})$ but since there is no definite parity on $y_{0}$ I can't say the angles are the same because it's like I'm taking them at different positions. This expression says that there is 2 points at the ellipse where the angles are the same but these points are not the same one unless $y_{0}=0$.

Comment: (a-b)=-(b-a)=b-a when?  tan (a-b) =-tan (b-a)=tan (b-a)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hint:

From the formula for $\tan(\alpha-\beta)$ one can deduce that
$$\arctan v-\arctan u=\arctan{v-u\over 1+uv}\ ,$$
up to multiples of $\pi$. The latter should be taken care of, if necessary.